# How come I cannot dismiss the view controller that I loaded?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I loaded a new view controller successfully with this IBAction that is triggered when a button is clicked.

```
-(IBAction)changeToAnotherView:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.newController == nil)
    {
        newController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    quizController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

However, my function to return to the old view in NewViewController.m does not build. Why?

```
- (IBAction)goBackToOldView:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

The build error I get is "No visible interface declares dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:".

---

Update:

lldb now outputs

```
"2012-04-30 21:31:56.530 Project32[10105:fb03] -[UIViewController goBackToOldView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c57f20
2012-04-30 21:31:56.531 Project32[10105:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController goBackToOldView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c57f20'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1649052 0x1bfdd0a 0x164aced 0x15aff00 0x15afce2 0x164aec9 0x2d05c2 0x50bd54 0x164aec9 0x2d05c2 0x2d055a 0x375b76 0x37603f 0x3752fe 0x2f5a30 0x2f5c56 0x2dc384 0x2cfaa9 0x2536fa9 0x161d1c5 0x1582022 0x158090a 0x157fdb4 0x157fccb 0x2535879 0x253593e 0x2cda9b 0x217d 0x20e5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)"
```

Interestingly, I implemented `goBackToOldView` in NewViewController:

```
- (IBAction)goBackToOldView:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Check if you do have it in the right place, comment the self dismissmodal.. part, and put a NSLog(@"Button pushed"); It will probably give you the same error which means that the button you are pressing is probably not connected to the correct action, explore it in the interface builder, the last tab of the inspector shows its connections. make sure there that it is pointing to the controller that has that newviewcontroler.m implemented

Comment: Thanks, you're right! Commenting out dismiss... and replacing it with `NSLog(@"go back!");` similarly fails. This is really weird though. I just dragged the line from my Nib file and selected goBack. Weird...

Comment: Hmm, do you have any debugging advice? The last tab of inspector does show the right function I believe.

Comment: Im not sure about what are you doing but, try using the assistant editor (second button of the xcode views) control drag the button to the header of the newviewcontroller and make it an action, now xcode will create an action for that on the m file. just add the nslog there and see if it works.

Comment: This is really weird. Dragging a line from the UI Button to function implementation in the assistant editor doesn't work either. Really really weird. The app still crashes due to a SIGABRT.

Comment: Drag it to the Header file, not the implementation file. But now that you mention that. IS your viewcontroller in the interface builder that contains that button, set as a controller of type "newviewcontroller" in the property inspector?

Answer (score 3):

Because that is not the correct function, it should be.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

(You can replace the nil on completition for a block to perform something after the controller has been dismissed.)

Comment: Thank you, but with - `(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}`, my app crashes when the IBAction is triggered. Do you perchance know why?

Comment: What Error do you get? write it exactly as you get it.

Comment: Thank you, I get "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" within my main function.

Comment: Usually SIGABRT come with the detail description in the error. Look at the console. it should appear there. we need to know the error description in order to give you the solution.

Comment: Well, that is the reason of your error, [UIViewController goBackToOldView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. which means that the new viewcontroller dosnt have that function implemented.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, as I noted above, I thought I did implement `goBackToOldView`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to the following and it should dismiss correctly.

```
-(IBAction)changeToAnotherView:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.newController == nil)
    {
        newController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    quizController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:newController animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)goBackToOldView:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but my app crashes when this IBAction is triggered. Do you know why?

Comment: I get a SIGABRT in my main function.